# ReplaceText in google script with regular expression not working

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

Am using google script to edit a google doc - I need to replace a specific portion of the doc. The text starts with AAA and ends with BBB with text (characters, digits, spaces) in between. I have tried replacetext with some regular expression but it isn't working. Any suggestions?

I have tried `.replacetext("AAA \* BBB", "FINAL")`, also - `\\code /(?\<=AAA).\*(?=BBB)/g` but none of it worked

Comment: Thanks a lot!- this works... the only glitch I am seeing is when I have a newline or other characters in between - any suggestion for that?

Comment: Try `AAA[\s\S]*?BBB`

Answer (score 0):

Try A{3}(.*)B{3} or A{3}([a-zA-z0-9 ]+)B{3} or A{3}((\w|\s)+)B{3}

- $1 is what's in the middle between AAA and BBB
- it's also the second element of the match array

[regex ref](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt)